# Books (and supporting material) that are useful in deconstructing one's intuition?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, intuition, self-learning

I recently came across the following problem from Paul Zeitz's book [The Art and Craft of Problem Solving](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Art-Craft-Problem-Solving/dp/0471789011). Given the image below, can you find a way to connect corresponding blocks (i.e. A to A, B to B, C to C), without having any of the connecting lines intersect one another?

[image: The Problem]

The question was an interesting one for me, because for the longest time I was convinced that it was impossible, and when I finally became acquainted with the solution, it took me quite a while to "accept" it.

Granted, I am not the sharpest tool in the shed, but upon introspection I also wonder if I am being hindered by the "intuition" I have come to develop, and implicitly "accept".

I wonder if it would be a helpful exercise to perhaps go through experiences that help me dismantle this intuition. The most accessible way I can think of of undergoing such a process would be by reading helpful books, given my limited resources. While I think problem solving books such as the one I am reading right now is good for this purpose as a side-effect of its initial intention ("teaching how to problem solve"), I wonder if there are books that are geared specifically towards deconstructing and examining "intution"?

[Prospective answerers, please attempt to answer this refinement of the question instead.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717328/intuition-analysis-deconstruction-reconstruction)

Comment: to be honest, this isn't intuition, this is lack of intuition. You don't need to *dismantle* it, you need to *build* it. (I don't mean that in a bad way, the first time I came across this, I was stumped too. The torus solution is nice.)

Comment: In that example, I think that it would be easier if you put A and C boxes in front of their partners, connect them and displace them to their correct position. Modifying the connections as you move them.

Comment: @Sabysachi: torus solution?

Comment: @boumol for a cheat solution, make a hole in the paper, fold it round to make a torus(donut). voila!

Comment: I could immediately see that there must be a solution.  Here's how.  It's clear that you can connect A to A and C to C by paths that don't touch.  Now imagine "cutting" the square open along those paths.  Since those cuts stop in the middle of the paper (i.e. at the positions of the top A and top C), they don't actually end up cutting the paper into two pieces (to do so, you'd have to finish cutting to the edge of the paper!).  So there must exist a path in the "cut open paper" from B to B.  Tape the cuts back together and you've got your solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this books can be useful : How to Solve it, by George Polya

Comment: if you could provide more precise reference inside the book (for example, chapter or pages) which points to result or hints for the OP the answer would be more useful :)